# css : border on wrapper not showing

Tags: html, css

what I've messed up? I try to give my wrapper a border right and left but it doesn't seem to be there.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="topInfo">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gptwQ/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gptwQ/4/

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gptwQ/5/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using `float:right` on  class `topInfo` try to put `overflow:hidden;` on class `wrapper`.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gptwQ/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the float element. Either remove it from #topInfo or add it to #wrapper.

Float elements dont have a width/height according to a none-floating parent. I suggest you remove the floats and learn how to use `display: inline-block` the proper way.
This is more difficult in the beginning, but in the long run will save you time.

[Here's a jsFIddle with inline-block (so removed the float)](http://jsfiddle.net/gptwQ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to `clear:both` after your topInfo div. Otherwise your "wrapper" is not wrapping.

**http://jsfiddle.net/gptwQ/3/**

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the elements if you use float elements. For this reason nowadays people are advising to use display:inline-block. In your case you can fix it in two ways.

**Answer1**: Add clear div at the end of content div in your wrapper.

```
 <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="topInfo">
        <p>some text</p>
   </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </div>
```

**Answer2:** Keep your HTML structure like that. But change the CSS classes like below. You need to take care of positioning right using absolute.

```
 .topInfo{
   width: 280px;
    background: red;
   color: #fff;
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   }
```